# page navigation using Jquery show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why my item doesn't come back? I did the `.show()` to the item.

```
<div id="back">< back</div>
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="content">My content</div>

$(function(){
    $('.item').on('click', function(){
        $(this).empty();
        $('.content').show(0,'', function(){
            $('#back').show();
        });
    });

    $('#back').on('click',function(){
        $('.item').show();
        $(this).hide();
        $('.content').hide();
    });
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling `$(this).empty()` on your `.item` click function. Change to `$(this).hide();`

[**.empty()**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) is removing the content from `.item` so while it is in fact showing when you click "< back" it appears to be hidden because the text has been removed. ([example of using .empty()](http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/5/))

```
$(function(){
   $('.item').on('click', function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $('.content').show(0,'', function(){
          $('#back').show();
      });
   });

   $('#back').on('click',function(){
      $('.item').show();
      $(this).hide();
      $('.content').hide();
   });
});
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/1/)